# Unable to locate element on http://automationpractice.com

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I used the below xpath to locate an element on http://automationpractice.com

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title = 'Choose from t-shirts, tops, blouses, short sleeves, long sleeves, tank tops, 3/4 sleeves and more. Find the cut that suits you the best!']")).click();
```

I'm not sure what the problem is.

It's working if I try to locate it with Linktext, but I want to know why the above xpath is not working.

Comment: There is no such **visible** element with _title_ as **Choose from t-shirts ...**. What is your exact _Manual Step_?

Answer (score 0):

Because the value of attribute: title includes new lines, but you given all string in one line.

Just simply copy the value into notepad, you can get following string:

```
You will find here all woman fashion collections.  
 This category includes all the basics of your wardrobe and much more: 
 shoes, accessories, printed t-shirts, feminine dresses, women's jeans!
```

You can use string function `normalize-space()` to remove new line and redundant space。

```
//a[normalize-space(@title)='Choose from t-shirts, tops, blouses, short sleeves, long sleeves, tank tops, 3/4 sleeves and more. Find the cut that suits you the best!']
```